# getting an error while initialize cx-for-spa / sap commerce

Tags: java, cmd, build.gradle, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm getting an error while initializing c-for-spa : I'll mention the error below. I would like to sort out the error and move to the next step.

```
BUILD FAILED
D:\2205\hybris\bin\platform\build.xml:13: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\2205\hybris\bin\platform\resources\ant\compiling.xml:95: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\2205\hybris\bin\platform\resources\ant\compiling.xml:153: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\2205\hybris\bin\platform\resources\ant\util.xml:13: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\2205\hybris\bin\platform\resources\ant\compiling.xml:160: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\2205\hybris\bin\platform\resources\ant\compiling.xml:333: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\2205\hybris\bin\platform\resources\ant\compiling.xml:538: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\2205\hybris\bin\platform\resources\ant\compiling.xml:589: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\2205\hybris\bin\platform\resources\ant\util.xml:94: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 5 minutes 36 seconds

> Task :recipes:cx-for-spa:buildSystem FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\2205\installer\recipes\cx-for-spa\build.gradle' line: 603

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':recipes:cx-for-spa:buildSystem'.
> external process returned non-zero exit code, command: [cmd, /c, set "ANT_OPTS=-Xmx2g -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dpolyglot.js.nashorn-compat=true -Dpolyglot.engine.WarnInterpreterOnly=false --add-exports java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.objects=ALL-UNNAMED" & set "PLATFORM_HOME=D:\2205\hybris\bin\platform" & set "ANT_HOME=D:\2205\hybris\bin\platform\apache-ant" & set "PATH=D:\2205\hybris\bin\platform\apache-ant\bin;%PATH%" & ant clean all]

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7m 14s
3 actionable tasks: 3 executed
Problem with java process - finished with non-zero exit code (1)
```

Comment: which version of hybris and java are you using?

Comment: Thank you for you response  @RaushanKumar

hybris version  :D:\2205\hybris\bin\platform\resources\tomcat-8.5.78\bin
( i think that this is the way to check the hybris version , if not could you please tell me the proper way to check out the hybris version ) 

java version : openjdk 17.0.6 2023-01-17 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment SapMachine (build 17.0.6+0-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM SapMachine (build 17.0.6+0-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: D:\2205\installer\customconfig In file:"build.parallel=true" => "#build.parallel=true"
try to comment this property

Comment: @RaushanKumar   I have  already commented that one out

Comment: then please run with --stacktrace, then it will give more info

Comment: @RaushanKumar , i am getting an errors like this :
D:\2205\hybris\bin\platform\build.xml:13: The following error occurred while executing this line:

Comment: try to open cmd as administrator then navigate to the path and execute the recipe command.

Comment: @RaushanKumar , I have tried to do it  with cmd (admin) but the same error i am receiving again :(

Comment: can you please share path variable of your system,I hope you shouldn't have installed node js and npm installed already, this is also an issue and java_home should be also correct.